# How do I display certain field from a Firestore document

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

so I've created a Firestore document with different fields:

```
db.collection("users").document("\(username)").setData([
    "username": username,
    "email": email,
    "Total calories burnt": 0,
    "league": "bronze"
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully written!")
    }
}
```

I want to be able to read only a certain field in the document, ie read the data stored in  `league:`. But it seems that using `.getDocument` would give everything in the document, while I only need one field. Is there any way to explicitly display the data stored in a certain field in a firebase document?

Comment: oh yah forgot to mention I'm coding this in xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both reading and access control are on a per-document basis, so you can't read only a single field from a document.

You can read the entire document, and display a single field of course, but you'll still be reading the entire document into the application.

If you don't want to do that (for example: because of access permissions, or to save bandwidth), consider creating an additional collection where each document has the same key, but only contains the field(s) for this use-case.

Comment: ok so how do i read the entire document and display only the single field

Comment: cuz that's exactly what i need

Comment: `document.get("league")`?

Answer (score 0):

First read entire doc if your doc id is xsana

```
 Const doc = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('xsana').get();
```

then get value  get value from doc if your field is username

```
Console.log(doc.data["username"]);
```

Try that and let us know

Comment: it gives me an error saying couldn't find const in scope